# reshape xml using xslt-3, splitting a record to many records if it has a certain element

Tags: xslt-3.0

given the following xml file, i need to select only those records that have a
`<marc:datafield tag="911"`, and out of each `911`, extract only the elements that have code h, or j: `<marc:subfield code="h">` or `<marc:subfield code="j">`. Both can have text values, ie digits and text. Then the selected records and elements should be altered, so we keep the 001 value as RECNO, and we add a unique incremental value of RECORD ID, starting with 1. If h or j is not present, the record does not have the corresponding element. Name_1 is the new element name for `, and Name_2 is the new element name for``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<marc:collection
    xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
    <marc:record>
        <marc:controlfield tag="001">7</marc:controlfield>
        </marc:datafield>
        <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="e">20171027</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="n">V.6</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="d">001000000918</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="a">001000000918</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="h">v.1</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="j">1686</marc:subfield>
        </marc:datafield>
        <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="e">20171027</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="n">V.6</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="d">001000000921</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="a">001000000921</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="h">v.2</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="j">1687</marc:subfield>
        </marc:datafield>
        <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="e">20171027</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="n">V.6</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="d">001000000920</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="a">001000000920</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="h">v.2</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="j">1687</marc:subfield>
        </marc:datafield>
        <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="e">20171027</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="n">V.6</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="d">001000000919</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="a">001000000919</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="h">v.1</marc:subfield>
            <marc:subfield code="j">1686</marc:subfield>
        </marc:datafield>
    </marc:record>
    <marc:record>
    <marc:controlfield tag="001">12481</marc:controlfield>
    <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="e">20160324</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="n">II.5</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="d">061000019180</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="a">061000019180</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="h">v.5</marc:subfield>
    </marc:datafield>
    <marc:datafield tag="911" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <marc:subfield code="o">KEN</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="b">MAIN</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="e">20160324</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="n">II.5</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="d">061000019181</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="a">061000019181</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="h">v.4</marc:subfield>
    </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
<marc:record>
    <marc:controlfield tag="001">1</marc:controlfield>
</marc:record>
</marc:collection>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<marc:collection
    xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
    <RECORD ID="1">   
        <RECNO>7</RECNO>
        <NAME_1>v.1</NAME_1>
        <NAME_2>1686</NAME_2>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>7</RECNO>
            <NAME_1>v.2</NAME_1>
            <NAME_2>1687</NAME_2>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>7</RECNO>
            <NAME_1>v.2</NAME_1>
            <NAME_2>1687</NAME_2>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="4">
            <RECNO>7</RECNO>
            <NAME_1>v.4</NAME_1>
            <NAME_2>16887</NAME_2>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="5">
            <RECNO>12481</RECNO>
            <NAME_1>v.5</NAME_1>
        </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="6">
            <RECNO>12481</RECNO>
            <NAME_1>v.4</NAME_1>
        </RECORD>
</marc:collection>
```

How the above result could be achieved, using xslt-3? (Saxon 9.8 HE)

Comment: your question is having a point. it is OR. If either h or j is not present, the generated record does not have the corresponding element.

Comment: So you know which elements you want to select/process and transform. Can you show us any attempt of an XSLT stylesheet? Also where are the values for the `NAME_1/NAME_2` result elements taken from? Where does `<NAME_2>a1687</NAME_2>` for instance result from?

Comment: NAME_1 stands for code h, and NAME_2 stands for code j. I tried to solve this using xsl:template match and xsl:copy-of select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any real splitting, you seem to simply want to map the `record/datafield[subfield/@code = ('h', 'j')]` elements to `RECORD` elements and then the `subfield` elements to the `NAME_1/NAME_2` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="record/datafield[subfield/@code = ('h', 'j')]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="datafield">
      <RECORD ID="{position()}">
          <RECNO>{ancestor::record/controlfield}</RECNO>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code = ('h', 'j')]"/>
      </RECORD>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subfield[@code = 'h']">
      <NAME_1>{.}</NAME_1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subfield[@code = 'j']">
      <NAME_2>{.}</NAME_2>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtrh

Comment: splitting in the meaning that one initial record has become 4 records in the output, thank you very much